# Download and save RTMP stream to the hard disk using LIBRTMP dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtmp

I am trying to download and save the RTMP stream. In the description of the library I found a method to maintain the flow. Please help me deal with this. Code that I use:

```
var
  MY_RTMP: RTMP;
  URL_str: string;
  MY_RTMPPacket: RTMPPacket;
  URL_char: PAnsiChar;
begin
  URL_str: = 'rtmp :/ / localhost: 1935/Video/test.stream';
  MY_RTMP: = RTMP_Alloc;
  RTMP_Init (MY_RTMP);
  RTMP_SetupURL (MY_RTMP, pcchar (URL_str));
  RTMP_EnableWrite (MY_RTMP);
  RTMP_Connect (MY_RTMP, MY_RTMPPacket);
  RTMP_ConnectStream (MY_RTMP, 0);
  RTMP_Read();
```

but it can only connect to the server
the use RTMP_Read (); I wanted to get help, because no idea what parameters must be passed to obtain a result.

LibRTMP definitions:

```
LIBRTMP(3)      LIBRTMP(3)
RTMPDump v2.4   2011-07-20  LIBRTMP(3)


NAME

librtmp − RTMPDump Real-Time Messaging Protocol API
LIBRARY

RTMPDump RTMP (librtmp, -lrtmp)
SYNOPSIS

#include <librtmp/rtmp.h>
DESCRIPTION

The Real-Time Messaging Protocol (RTMP) is used for streaming multimedia content across a TCP/IP network. This API provides most client functions and a few server functions needed to support RTMP, RTMP tunneled in HTTP (RTMPT), encrypted RTMP (RTMPE), RTMP over SSL/TLS (RTMPS) and tunneled variants of these encrypted types (RTMPTE, RTMPTS). The basic RTMP specification has been published by Adobe but this API was reverse-engineered without use of the Adobe specification. As such, it may deviate from any published specifications but it usually duplicates the actual behavior of the original Adobe clients.
The RTMPDump software package includes a basic client utility program in rtmpdump(1), some sample servers, and a library used to provide programmatic access to the RTMP protocol. This man page gives an overview of the RTMP library routines. These routines are found in the -lrtmp library. Many other routines are also available, but they are not documented yet.

The basic interaction is as follows. A session handle is created using RTMP_Alloc() and initialized using RTMP_Init(). All session parameters are provided using RTMP_SetupURL(). The network connection is established using RTMP_Connect(), and then the RTMP session is established using RTMP_ConnectStream(). The stream is read using RTMP_Read(). A client can publish a stream by calling RTMP_EnableWrite() before the RTMP_Connect() call, and then using RTMP_Write() after the session is established. While a stream is playing it may be paused and unpaused using RTMP_Pause(). The stream playback position can be moved using RTMP_Seek(). When RTMP_Read() returns 0 bytes, the stream is complete and may be closed using RTMP_Close(). The session handle is freed using RTMP_Free().

All data is transferred using FLV format. The basic session requires an RTMP URL. The RTMP URL format is of the form

  rtmp[t][e|s]://hostname[:port][/app[/playpath]]
Plain rtmp, as well as tunneled and encrypted sessions are supported.

Additional options may be specified by appending space-separated key=value pairs to the URL. Special characters in values may need to be escaped to prevent misinterpretation by the option parser. The escape encoding uses a backslash followed by two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII value of the character. E.g., spaces must be escaped as \20 and backslashes must be escaped as \5c.

OPTIONS

Network Parameters

These options define how to connect to the media server.
socks=host:port
Use the specified SOCKS4 proxy.
Connection Parameters

These options define the content of the RTMP Connect request packet. If correct values are not provided, the media server will reject the connection attempt.
app=name
Name of application to connect to on the RTMP server. Overrides the app in the RTMP URL. Sometimes the librtmp URL parser cannot determine the app name automatically, so it must be given explicitly using this option.
tcUrl=url
URL of the target stream. Defaults to rtmp[t][e|s]://host[:port]/app.
pageUrl=url
URL of the web page in which the media was embedded. By default no value will be sent.
swfUrl=url
URL of the SWF player for the media. By default no value will be sent.
flashVer=version
Version of the Flash plugin used to run the SWF player. The default is "LNX 10,0,32,18".
conn=type:data
Append arbitrary AMF data to the Connect message. The type must be B for Boolean, N for number, S for string, O for object, or Z for null. For Booleans the data must be either 0 or 1 for FALSE or TRUE, respectively. Likewise for Objects the data must be 0 or 1 to end or begin an object, respectively. Data items in subobjects may be named, by prefixing the type with 'N' and specifying the name before the value, e.g. NB:myFlag:1. This option may be used multiple times to construct arbitrary AMF sequences. E.g.
  conn=B:1 conn=S:authMe conn=O:1 conn=NN:code:1.23 conn=NS:flag:ok conn=O:0
Session Parameters

These options take effect after the Connect request has succeeded.
playpath=path
Overrides the playpath parsed from the RTMP URL. Sometimes the rtmpdump URL parser cannot determine the correct playpath automatically, so it must be given explicitly using this option.
playlist=0|1
If the value is 1 or TRUE, issue a set_playlist command before sending the play command. The playlist will just contain the current playpath. If the value is 0 or FALSE, the set_playlist command will not be sent. The default is FALSE.
live=0|1
Specify that the media is a live stream. No resuming or seeking in live streams is possible.
subscribe=path
Name of live stream to subscribe to. Defaults to playpath.
start=num
Start at num seconds into the stream. Not valid for live streams.
stop=num
Stop at num seconds into the stream.
buffer=num
Set buffer time to num milliseconds. The default is 30000.
timeout=num
Timeout the session after num seconds without receiving any data from the server. The default is 120.
Security Parameters

These options handle additional authentication requests from the server.
token=key
Key for SecureToken response, used if the server requires SecureToken authentication.
jtv=JSON
JSON token used by legacy Justin.tv servers. Invokes NetStream.Authenticate.UsherToken
swfVfy=0|1
If the value is 1 or TRUE, the SWF player is retrieved from the specified swfUrl for performing SWF Verification. The SWF hash and size (used in the verification step) are computed automatically. Also the SWF information is cached in a .swfinfo file in the user's home directory, so that it doesn't need to be retrieved and recalculated every time. The .swfinfo file records the SWF URL, the time it was fetched, the modification timestamp of the SWF file, its size, and its hash. By default, the cached info will be used for 30 days before re-checking.
swfAge=days
Specify how many days to use the cached SWF info before re-checking. Use 0 to always check the SWF URL. Note that if the check shows that the SWF file has the same modification timestamp as before, it will not be retrieved again.
EXAMPLES

An example character string suitable for use with RTMP_SetupURL():
  "rtmp://flashserver:1935/ondemand/thefile swfUrl=http://flashserver/player.swf swfVfy=1"
ENVIRONMENT

HOME
The value of $HOME is used as the location for the .swfinfo file.
FILES

$HOME/.swfinfo
Cache of SWF Verification information
SEE ALSO

rtmpdump(1), rtmpgw(8)
AUTHORS

Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team 
<http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu>
```

Code used :

```
{$IFDEF FPC}
  {$MODE DELPHI}
  {$PACKRECORDS C}
{$ENDIF}

unit lrtmp;

interface

uses windows, sockets, WinSock ;

Const
{$ifdef windows}
  LibRtmp = 'librtmp'; // Library name
  { matching lib version for librtmp.dll, needed for initialization }
  RTMP_LIBRTMP_VER_STRING='2.3';
{$else windows}
  LibRtmp = 'rtmp'; // Library name
  { matching lib version for librtmp, needed for initialization }
  RTMP_LIBRTMP_VER_STRING='2.3';
{$endif windows}

//{$I inttypes}

{AMF Constants}
Const
    AMF_NUMBER = 0;
    AMF_BOOLEAN = 1;
    AMF_STRING = 2;
    AMF_OBJECT = 3;
    AMF_MOVIECLIP = 4;
    AMF_NULL = 5;
    AMF_UNDEFINED = 6;
    AMF_REFERENCE = 7;
    AMF_ECMA_ARRAY = 8;
    AMF_OBJECT_END = 9;
    AMF_STRICT_ARRAY = 10;
    AMF_DATE = 11;
    AMF_LONG_STRING = 12;
    AMF_UNSUPPORTED = 13;
    AMF_RECORDSET = 14;
    AMF_XML_DOC = 15;
    AMF_TYPED_OBJECT = 16;
    AMF_AVMPLUS = 17;
    AMF_INVALID = $ff;
    AMF3_UNDEFINED = 0;
    AMF3_NULL = 1;
    AMF3_FALSE = 2;
    AMF3_TRUE = 3;
    AMF3_INTEGER = 4;
    AMF3_DOUBLE = 5;
    AMF3_STRING = 6;
    AMF3_XML_DOC = 7;
    AMF3_DATE = 8;
    AMF3_ARRAY = 9;
    AMF3_OBJECT = 10;
    AMF3_XML = 11;
    AMF3_BYTE_ARRAY = 12;

{RTMP Constants}
const
  RTMP_LIB_VERSION = $020300;  
  RTMP_FEATURE_HTTP = $01;  
  RTMP_FEATURE_ENC = $02;  
  RTMP_FEATURE_SSL = $04;  
  RTMP_FEATURE_MFP = $08;  
  RTMP_FEATURE_WRITE = $10;  
  RTMP_FEATURE_HTTP2 = $20;  
  RTMP_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED = -(1);  
  RTMP_PROTOCOL_RTMP = 0;  
  RTMP_PROTOCOL_RTMPE = RTMP_FEATURE_ENC;  
  RTMP_PROTOCOL_RTMPT = RTMP_FEATURE_HTTP;  
  RTMP_PROTOCOL_RTMPS = RTMP_FEATURE_SSL;  
  RTMP_PROTOCOL_RTMPTE = RTMP_FEATURE_HTTP or RTMP_FEATURE_ENC;  
  RTMP_PROTOCOL_RTMPTS = RTMP_FEATURE_HTTP or RTMP_FEATURE_SSL;  
  RTMP_PROTOCOL_RTMFP = RTMP_FEATURE_MFP;  
  RTMP_DEFAULT_CHUNKSIZE = 128;  
  RTMP_BUFFER_CACHE_SIZE = 16*1024;  
  RTMP_CHANNELS = 65600;  
  RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_AUDIO = $08;  
  RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_VIDEO = $09;  
  RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_INFO = $12;  
  RTMP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE = 18;  
  RTMP_PACKET_SIZE_LARGE = 0;  
  RTMP_PACKET_SIZE_MEDIUM = 1;  
  RTMP_PACKET_SIZE_SMALL = 2;  
  RTMP_PACKET_SIZE_MINIMUM = 3;  
  RTMP_LF_AUTH = $0001;  
  RTMP_LF_LIVE = $0002;  
  RTMP_LF_SWFV = $0004;  
  RTMP_LF_PLST = $0008;  
  RTMP_LF_BUFX = $0010;  
  RTMP_LF_FTCU = $0020;  
  RTMP_SWF_HASHLEN = 32;  
  RTMP_READ_HEADER = $01;  
  RTMP_READ_RESUME = $02;  
  RTMP_READ_NO_IGNORE = $04;  
  RTMP_READ_GOTKF = $08;  
  RTMP_READ_GOTFLVK = $10;  
  RTMP_READ_SEEKING = $20;  
  RTMP_READ_COMPLETE = -(3);
  RTMP_READ_ERROR = -(2);  
  RTMP_READ_EOF = -(1);  
  RTMP_READ_IGNORE = 0;

var
  FSocket  : TSocket;
  SockAddrB : TSockAddr;
  WSAData  : TWSAData;

{AMF Types}
Type
 char = AnsiChar;
 cint = longint;
 cchar = shortint;
 pcchar = ^cchar;
 uint8_t  = Byte;
 uint32_t = LongWord;
 int8_t = char;
 int32_t = LongInt;
 unsigned_char = Byte;
 unsigned_int = LongWord;
 unsigned_short = Word;
 int16_t = smallint;
 cuchar = byte;
 pcuchar = ^cuchar;
 cushort = Word;
 cuint = LongWord;
 cshort = SmallInt;
 clong = LongInt;

    AVal = record
          av_val : pcchar;
          av_len : cint;
        end;
    PAVal  = ^AVal;
    AMF3ClassDef = record
          cd_name : AVal;
          cd_externalizable : cchar;
          cd_dynamic : cchar;
          cd_num : cint;
          cd_props : PAVal;
        end;
    PAMF3ClassDef  = ^AMF3ClassDef;
    AMF3DataType =  Longint;
    PAMF3DataType  = ^AMF3DataType;
    AMFDataType =  Longint;
    PAMFDataType  = ^AMFDataType;
    AMFObjectProperty = record
          {undefined structure}
        end;
    PAMFObjectProperty  = ^AMFObjectProperty;
    AMFObject = record
          o_num : cint;
          o_props : PAMFObjectProperty;
        end;
    PAMFObject  = ^AMFObject;

{RTMP Types}

Type
  TArray0toRTMP_SWF_HASHLEN1OfUint8_t = array[0..(RTMP_SWF_HASHLEN)-1] of uint8_t;
  TArray0toRTMP_SWF_HASHLEN101OfCchar = array[0..(RTMP_SWF_HASHLEN+10)-1] of cchar;
  TArray0toRTMP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE1OfCchar = array[0..(RTMP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE)-1] of cchar;
  TArray0toRTMP_CHANNELS1OfCint = array[0..(RTMP_CHANNELS)-1] of cint;
  TArray0toRTMP_BUFFER_CACHE_SIZE1OfCchar = array[0..(RTMP_BUFFER_CACHE_SIZE)-1] of cchar;
  TArray0to6OfPcchar = array[0..6] of pcchar;

  SockAddr = record
   sa_family: u_short;
   sa_data: array[0..13] of Char;
  end;

  RTMPChunk = record
      c_headerSize : cint;
      c_chunkSize : cint;
      c_chunk : pcchar;
      c_header : TArray0toRTMP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE1OfCchar;
    end;

  PRTMPChunk  = ^RTMPChunk;

  RTMPPacket = record
      m_headerType : uint8_t;
      m_packetType : uint8_t;
      m_hasAbsTimestamp : uint8_t;
      m_nChannel : cint;
      m_nTimeStamp : uint32_t;
      m_nInfoField2 : int32_t;
      m_nBodySize : uint32_t;
      m_nBytesRead : uint32_t;
      m_chunk : PRTMPChunk;
      m_body : pcchar;
    end;

  PRTMPPacket  = ^RTMPPacket;
  TArray0toRTMP_CHANNELS1OfPRTMPPacket = array[0..(RTMP_CHANNELS)-1] of PRTMPPacket;

  RTMPSockBuf = record
      sb_socket : cint;
      sb_size : cint;
      sb_start : pcchar;
      sb_buf : TArray0toRTMP_BUFFER_CACHE_SIZE1OfCchar;
      sb_timedout : cint;
      sb_ssl : pointer;
    end;

  RTMP_LNK = record
      hostname : AVal;
      sockshost : AVal;
      playpath0 : AVal;
      playpath : AVal;
      tcUrl : AVal;
      swfUrl : AVal;
      pageUrl : AVal;
      app : AVal;
      auth : AVal;
      flashVer : AVal;
      subscribepath : AVal;
      token : AVal;
      extras : AMFObject;
      edepth : cint;
      seekTime : cint;
      stopTime : cint;
      lFlags : cint;
      swfAge : cint;
      protocol : cint;
      timeout : cint;
      socksport : cushort;
      port : cushort;
      dh : pointer;
      rc4keyIn : pointer;
      rc4keyOut : pointer;
      SWFSize : uint32_t;
      SWFHash : TArray0toRTMP_SWF_HASHLEN1OfUint8_t;
      SWFVerificationResponse : TArray0toRTMP_SWF_HASHLEN101OfCchar;
    end;

  RTMP_READ = record
      buf : pcchar;
      bufpos : pcchar;
      buflen : cuint;
      timestamp : uint32_t;
      dataType : uint8_t;
      flags : uint8_t;
      status : int8_t;
      initialFrameType : uint8_t;
      nResumeTS : uint32_t;
      metaHeader : pcchar;
      initialFrame : pcchar;
      nMetaHeaderSize : uint32_t;
      nInitialFrameSize : uint32_t;
      nIgnoredFrameCounter : uint32_t;
      nIgnoredFlvFrameCounter : uint32_t;
    end;

  RTMP_METHOD = record
      name : AVal;
      num : cint;
    end;

  PRTMP_METHOD  = ^RTMP_METHOD;

  RTMP = record
      m_inChunkSize : cint;
      m_outChunkSize : cint;
      m_nBWCheckCounter : cint;
      m_nBytesIn : cint;
      m_nBytesInSent : cint;
      m_nBufferMS : cint;
      m_stream_id : cint;
      m_mediaChannel : cint;
      m_mediaStamp : uint32_t;
      m_pauseStamp : uint32_t;
      m_pausing : cint;
      m_nServerBW : cint;
      m_nClientBW : cint;
      m_nClientBW2 : uint8_t;
      m_bPlaying : uint8_t;
      m_bSendEncoding : uint8_t;
      m_bSendCounter : uint8_t;
      m_numInvokes : cint;
      m_numCalls : cint;
      m_methodCalls : PRTMP_METHOD;
      m_vecChannelsIn : TArray0toRTMP_CHANNELS1OfPRTMPPacket;
      m_vecChannelsOut : TArray0toRTMP_CHANNELS1OfPRTMPPacket;
      m_channelTimestamp : TArray0toRTMP_CHANNELS1OfCint;
      m_fAudioCodecs : double;
      m_fVideoCodecs : double;
      m_fEncoding : double;
      m_fDuration : double;
      m_msgCounter : cint;
      m_polling : cint;
      m_resplen : cint;
      m_unackd : cint;
      m_clientID : AVal;
      m_read : RTMP_READ;
      m_write : RTMPPacket;
      m_sb : RTMPSockBuf;
      Link : RTMP_LNK;
    end;

  PRTMP  = ^RTMP;
  PRTMP_LNK  = ^RTMP_LNK;
  PRTMP_READ  = ^RTMP_READ;
  PRTMPSockBuf  = ^RTMPSockBuf;

{RTMP Variables}
var
    RTMPProtocolStringsLower : Array [0..6] of Pcchar;    //array[0..(RTMP_CHANNELS)-1]
    RTMP_DefaultFlashVer : AVal;
    RTMP_ctrlC : cint;
    {RTMPProtocolStringsLower : TArray0to6OfPcchar; cvar; external;
    RTMP_DefaultFlashVer : AVal;cvar;external;
    RTMP_ctrlC : cint;cvar;external;}

 {AMF Functions}
function AMF_EncodeString(output:pcchar; outend:pcchar; var str:AVal):pcchar;cdecl;external 'librtmp.dll' name 'AMF_EncodeString';  //LibRtmp = 'librtmp';
function AMF_EncodeNumber(output:pcchar; outend:pcchar; dVal:double):pcchar;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_EncodeNumber';
function AMF_EncodeInt16(output:pcchar; outend:pcchar; nVal:cshort):pcchar;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_EncodeInt16';
function AMF_EncodeInt24(output:pcchar; outend:pcchar; nVal:cint):pcchar;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_EncodeInt24';
function AMF_EncodeInt32(output:pcchar; outend:pcchar; nVal:cint):pcchar;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_EncodeInt32';
function AMF_EncodeBoolean(output:pcchar; outend:pcchar; bVal:cint):pcchar;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_EncodeBoolean';
function AMF_EncodeNamedString(output:pcchar; outend:pcchar; var name:AVal; var value:AVal):pcchar;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_EncodeNamedString';
function AMF_EncodeNamedNumber(output:pcchar; outend:pcchar; var name:AVal; dVal:double):pcchar;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_EncodeNamedNumber';
function AMF_EncodeNamedBoolean(output:pcchar; outend:pcchar; var name:AVal; bVal:cint):pcchar;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_EncodeNamedBoolean';
function AMF_DecodeInt16(data:pcchar):cushort;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_DecodeInt16';
function AMF_DecodeInt24(data:pcchar):cuint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_DecodeInt24';
function AMF_DecodeInt32(data:pcchar):cuint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_DecodeInt32';
procedure AMF_DecodeString(data:pcchar; var str:AVal);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_DecodeString';
procedure AMF_DecodeLongString(data:pcchar; var str:AVal);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_DecodeLongString';
function AMF_DecodeBoolean(data:pcchar):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_DecodeBoolean';
function AMF_DecodeNumber(data:pcchar):double;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_DecodeNumber';
function AMF_Encode(var obj:AMFObject; pBuffer:pcchar; pBufEnd:pcchar):pcchar;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_Encode';
function AMF_Decode(var obj:AMFObject; pBuffer:pcchar; nSize:cint; bDecodeName:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_Decode';
function AMF_DecodeArray(var obj:AMFObject; pBuffer:pcchar; nSize:cint; nArrayLen:cint; bDecodeName:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_DecodeArray';
function AMF3_Decode(var obj:AMFObject; pBuffer:pcchar; nSize:cint; bDecodeName:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF3_Decode';
procedure AMF_Dump(var obj:AMFObject);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_Dump';
procedure AMF_Reset(var obj:AMFObject);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_Reset';
procedure AMF_AddProp(var obj:AMFObject; var prop:AMFObjectProperty);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_AddProp';
function AMF_CountProp(var obj:AMFObject):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_CountProp';
function AMF_GetProp(var obj:AMFObject; var name:AVal; nIndex:cint):PAMFObjectProperty;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF_GetProp';
function AMFProp_GetType(var prop:AMFObjectProperty):AMFDataType;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_GetType';
procedure AMFProp_SetNumber(var prop:AMFObjectProperty; dval:double);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_SetNumber';
procedure AMFProp_SetBoolean(var prop:AMFObjectProperty; bflag:cint);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_SetBoolean';
procedure AMFProp_SetString(var prop:AMFObjectProperty; var str:AVal);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_SetString';
procedure AMFProp_SetObject(var prop:AMFObjectProperty; var obj:AMFObject);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_SetObject';
procedure AMFProp_GetName(var prop:AMFObjectProperty; var name:AVal);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_GetName';
procedure AMFProp_SetName(var prop:AMFObjectProperty; var name:AVal);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_SetName';
function AMFProp_GetNumber(var prop:AMFObjectProperty):double;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_GetNumber';
function AMFProp_GetBoolean(var prop:AMFObjectProperty):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_GetBoolean';
procedure AMFProp_GetString(var prop:AMFObjectProperty; var str:AVal);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_GetString';
procedure AMFProp_GetObject(var prop:AMFObjectProperty; var obj:AMFObject);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_GetObject';
function AMFProp_IsValid(var prop:AMFObjectProperty):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_IsValid';
function AMFProp_Encode(var prop:AMFObjectProperty; pBuffer:pcchar; pBufEnd:pcchar):pcchar;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_Encode';
function AMF3Prop_Decode(var prop:AMFObjectProperty; pBuffer:pcchar; nSize:cint; bDecodeName:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF3Prop_Decode';
function AMFProp_Decode(var prop:AMFObjectProperty; pBuffer:pcchar; nSize:cint; bDecodeName:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_Decode';
procedure AMFProp_Dump(var prop:AMFObjectProperty);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_Dump';
procedure AMFProp_Reset(var prop:AMFObjectProperty);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMFProp_Reset';
procedure AMF3CD_AddProp(var cd:AMF3ClassDef; var prop:AVal);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF3CD_AddProp';
function AMF3CD_GetProp(var cd:AMF3ClassDef; idx:cint):PAVal;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'AMF3CD_GetProp';

{RTMP Functions}
procedure RTMPPacket_Reset(var p:RTMPPacket);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMPPacket_Reset';
procedure RTMPPacket_Dump(var p:RTMPPacket);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMPPacket_Dump';
function RTMPPacket_Alloc(var p:RTMPPacket; nSize:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMPPacket_Alloc';
procedure RTMPPacket_Free(var p:RTMPPacket);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMPPacket_Free';
function RTMP_GetTime:uint32_t;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_GetTime';
function RTMP_ParseURL(url:pcchar; var protocol:cint; var host:AVal; var port:cuint; var playpath:AVal; 
           var app:AVal):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_ParseURL';
procedure RTMP_ParsePlaypath(var input:AVal; var output:AVal);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_ParsePlaypath';
procedure RTMP_SetBufferMS(var r:RTMP; size:cint);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SetBufferMS';
procedure RTMP_UpdateBufferMS(var r:RTMP);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_UpdateBufferMS';
function RTMP_SetOpt(var r:RTMP; var opt:AVal; var arg:AVal):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SetOpt';
function RTMP_SetupURL(var r:RTMP; url:pcchar):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SetupURL';
procedure RTMP_SetupStream(var r:RTMP; protocol:cint; var hostname:AVal; port:cuint; var sockshost:AVal; 
            var playpath:AVal; var tcUrl:AVal; var swfUrl:AVal; var pageUrl:AVal; var app:AVal; 
            var auth:AVal; var swfSHA256Hash:AVal; swfSize:uint32_t; var flashVer:AVal; var subscribepath:AVal; 
            dStart:cint; dStop:cint; bLiveStream:cint; timeout:clong);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SetupStream';
function RTMP_Connect(var r:RTMP; var cp:RTMPPacket):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_Connect';
function RTMP_Connect0(var r:RTMP; var svc:sockaddr):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_Connect0';
function RTMP_Connect1(var r:RTMP; var cp:RTMPPacket):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_Connect1';
function RTMP_Serve(var r:RTMP):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_Serve';
function RTMP_ReadPacket(var r:RTMP; var packet:RTMPPacket):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_ReadPacket';
function RTMP_SendPacket(var r:RTMP; var packet:RTMPPacket; queue:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SendPacket';
function RTMP_SendChunk(var r:RTMP; var chunk:RTMPChunk):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SendChunk';
function RTMP_IsConnected(var r:RTMP):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_IsConnected';
function RTMP_Socket(var r:RTMP):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_Socket';
function RTMP_IsTimedout(var r:RTMP):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_IsTimedout';
function RTMP_GetDuration(var r:RTMP):double;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_GetDuration';
function RTMP_ToggleStream(var r:RTMP):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_ToggleStream';
function RTMP_ConnectStream(var r:RTMP; seekTime:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_ConnectStream';
function RTMP_ReconnectStream(var r:RTMP; seekTime:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_ReconnectStream';
procedure RTMP_DeleteStream(var r:RTMP);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_DeleteStream';
function RTMP_GetNextMediaPacket(var r:RTMP; var packet:RTMPPacket):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_GetNextMediaPacket';
function RTMP_ClientPacket(var r:RTMP; var packet:RTMPPacket):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_ClientPacket';
procedure RTMP_Init(var r:RTMP);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_Init';
procedure RTMP_Close(var r:RTMP);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_Close';
function RTMP_Alloc:RTMP;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_Alloc';
procedure RTMP_Free(var r:RTMP);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_Free';
procedure RTMP_EnableWrite(var r:RTMP);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_EnableWrite';
function RTMP_LibVersion:cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_LibVersion';
procedure RTMP_UserInterrupt;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_UserInterrupt';
function RTMP_SendCtrl(var r:RTMP; nType:cshort; nObject:cuint; nTime:cuint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SendCtrl';
function RTMP_SendPause(var r:RTMP; DoPause:cint; dTime:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SendPause';
function RTMP_Pause(var r:RTMP; DoPause:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_Pause';
function RTMP_FindFirstMatchingProperty(var obj:AMFObject; var name:AVal; var p:AMFObjectProperty):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_FindFirstMatchingProperty';
function RTMPSockBuf_Fill(var sb:RTMPSockBuf):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMPSockBuf_Fill';
function RTMPSockBuf_Send(var sb:RTMPSockBuf; buf:pcchar; len:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMPSockBuf_Send';
function RTMPSockBuf_Close(var sb:RTMPSockBuf):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMPSockBuf_Close';
function RTMP_SendCreateStream(var r:RTMP):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SendCreateStream';
function RTMP_SendSeek(var r:RTMP; dTime:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SendSeek';
function RTMP_SendServerBW(var r:RTMP):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SendServerBW';
function RTMP_SendClientBW(var r:RTMP):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_SendClientBW';
procedure RTMP_DropRequest(var r:RTMP; i:cint; freeit:cint);cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_DropRequest';
function RTMP_ReadData(var r:RTMP; buf:pcchar; size:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_ReadData';
function RTMP_WriteData(var r:RTMP; buf:pcchar; size:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_WriteData';
function RTMP_HashSWF(url:pcchar; var size:cuint; hash:pcuchar; age:cint):cint;cdecl;external 'librtmp' name 'RTMP_HashSWF';

implementation


end.
```

Comment: -1 How are we expected to know the answer to this? Please provide links to the documentation of this library which I expect you have already read. Please provide links to your Pascal header translation. Please provide what you expect the code to do and details of how it fails. Please show us that you care about this question. If we believe that you care, there's more chance that we will care. At the moment it looks as though you are lazy and want us to do everything for you. Please put more effort into your questions. If you can't improve the question, I'll vote to close it. [faq]

Comment: documentation library librtmp: [link](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html)

Comment: Not in a comment. Add the links to the question. Click on the **edit** link below the question and improve the question. Anyway, where's the call to `RTMP_Read`?

Comment: unit that I use (code delphi): [link](http://pastebin.com/fGRdXhjJ)

Comment: I mean it. Please edit the question. It's no use supplying the detail in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you need to call

```
RTMP_Read()
```

repeatedly to read the stream. You pass a buffer to that function and the function fills it out with the next part of the stream. When the function returns 0 it means that the entire stream has been read.

The code would be something like this:

```
procedure ReadStream(rtmp: RTMP; Stream: TStream);
var
  Buffer: array [0..16384-1] of Byte;//16kB buffer
  BytesRead: Integer;
begin
  while True do 
  begin
    BytesRead := RTMP_Read(rtmp, @Buffer[0], SizeOf(Buffer));
    if BytesRead=0 then
      exit;
    Stream.WriteBuffer(@Buffer[0], BytesRead);
  end;
```

The documentation I'm looking at has the function named `RTMP_Read`. But your import unit seems to call it `RTMP_ReadData`. I'm not sure where that discrepancy comes from.

I'm also not convinced by the header translation that you use. I would write `PByte` instead of `pcchar` and I would write `Integer` instead of `cint`.

Comment: the use RTMP_Read (); I wanted to get help, because no idea what parameters must be passed to obtain a result.

Comment: Please don't feel you have to accept immediately. Feel free to try this out and if I'm utterly wrong then don't accept! I know I'm being bossy! Thanks for listening and heeding the advice.

Comment: I have to re-use your patience. I absolutely do not understand the options that are described in RTMP_READ = record. The record has 15 parameters which are not known to me. Please help solve this problem, it is very important to me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that. I think I answered the question you asked here.